# Reading CSV files into separate data frames using FOR Loop

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I have 600 `csv` files that I want to read to separate data frames using `pd.read.csv`. I have tried the code below.

```
for stock in stock_list:
    df_stock = pd.read_csv("D:/Stocks/CSV/" + stock + ".csv")
```

I want every dataframe to be stored separately as df_the respective stock name in stock_list (for example `df_pfizer`, `df_ICBC` and so on) but instead my code is reading it into a single dataframe. The stock names are in the list `stock_list`.

Answer (score 2):

Having 600 variables is not handleable, you should use a dictionary.

```
df_dict = {}
for stock in stock_list:
    df_dict[stock] = pd.read_csv("D:/Stocks/CSV/" + stock + ".csv")
```

... or:

```
df_dict = {stock: pd.read_csv("D:/Stocks/CSV/" + stock + ".csv") for stock in stock_list}
```

Comment: what is `stock_list` in the dictionary comp?

Comment: @Umar.H Isn't it your list of stock names ? You can then retrieve any dataframe from the dictionary with a name, like this: `df_dict["some_name"]`. Please check the [python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the dataframes into a python [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
df_stocks = {}
for stock in stock_list:
    df_stock = pd.read_csv("D:/Stocks/CSV/" + stock + ".csv")
    df_stocks[stock] = df_stock
```

And to access any dataframe:

```
df_stocks['df_pfizer']
```

will return the `'df_pfizer'` dataframe,

```
df_stocks['df_ICBC']
```

will return the `df_stocks['df_ICBC']` dataframe, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you need to first create a single dataframe then seperate them based on the stockname with a dictionary comp.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.concat(
                [pd.read_csv(f) for f in Path(r"D:/Stocks/CSV/").glob('*.csv')]
              )

stock_dfs = {stock : frame for stock,frame in dfs.groupby('stock_list')}
```

---

then you can call each df by its key

```
stock_dfs['df_pfizer']
```

Comment: Thanks Umar for such a prompt reply. But i want separate dataframes. Isnt there a way to create separate dataframes with respective names?

Comment: creating n number of variables is not recommended. use a container like a `dictionary` I wasn't sure if you wanted to seperated by the `stock_list` column or the file name. that said, the above method will handle that for you.